# Request help for a batch script to kill a process after a program is closed

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do I modify the following batch script to kill a process instead of a task?

For example, if BBB.exe once executed runs as a process, how would I kill that process once AAA.exe is closed?

To clarify, if you open task manager, tasks are listed under the "applications" tab and a process is listed under the "processes" tab. The program represented as "BBB.exe" that I'm trying to kill immediately once AAA.exe is closed only opens to the system tray and not the task bar and therefore is not present in the "applications" tab but only the "processes" tab when open. The following batch file does not have any effect on ending program "BBB.exe" even when the machine is ran with admin privileges. I've seen the "Process.Kill()" command but I'm not sure how to properly utilize it.

Thanks in advance.

```
@Echo off
CD "C:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX"
start AAA.exe

CD "C:\XXX\XXX"
start BBB.exe

:TEST
Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq AAA.exe" 2>NUL | Find /I /N AAA.exe>NUL 
If "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto ACTIVE

:DEAD
Taskkill /F /IM BBB.exe
Exit

:ACTIVE
Timeout /T 1
Goto TEST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem is.

The issue lies in that the "taskkill" command was never being deployed because command prompt remained in the directory of BBB.exe where the "taskkill" executable doesn't exist.

Simply changing the directoy to either "system32" or "syswow64" (depending on the OS installation) after executing both programs and before running the "taskkill" command in the batch file solved the issue.

Comment: The only way that `taskkill.exe` didn't work is if you've broken your system environment, by overwriting its default `%PATH%` variable to not include `%SystemRoot%\System32`. Your solution therefore has absolutely nothing to do with programming, or something we could have helped you with, because you provided no information whatsoever for us to determine that you'd broken your environment. There also is no reason to have your current working directory changed just to use `taskkill.exe`, what you should have done was to write robust code, using full paths, instead of relying upon `%PATH%`.

Comment: You state what the System enviroment variables should be but not what to name them when recreating. What do I name the "%SystemRoot%\System32" variable so that command prompt opens with that as the default?